# Publishing marker and point cloud at the same time

Tags: c++, ros

I was trying to publish point cloud and marker arrow at the same time from a ROS node by using the code below. When I try to display them both in rviz I cannot see them both.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>

ros::Publisher pub;
ros::Publisher arrow_pub;
void
cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{

// ** conversion of ros message to pcl
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> output;
pcl::fromROSMsg(*input,output);

int h = 480;
int w = 640;
pcl::PointXYZRGB p[w][h];

for(int i=0;i<=w;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<=h;j++)
    {
      p[i][j] = output.at(i,j);
    }
 }

visualization_msgs::Marker arrow;

arrow.header.frame_id = "/camera_depth_frame";
arrow.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

arrow.ns = "example";
arrow.id = 1;

arrow.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
arrow.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;

arrow.pose.position.x = p[55][55].x;
arrow.pose.position.y = p[55][55].y;
arrow.pose.position.z = p[55][55].z;

arrow.pose.orientation.x = 45;
arrow.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
arrow.pose.orientation.z = 45;
arrow.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

arrow.scale.x= 5;
arrow.scale.y= 0.1;
arrow.scale.z = 0.1;

arrow.color.g = 0.0f;
arrow.color.a = 1.0;
arrow.color.r = 0.0f;
arrow.color.b = 1.0f;

arrow.lifetime = ros::Duration();


// ** conversion of pcl messag to ros
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
pcl::toROSMsg(output,cloud);

pub.publish(cloud);
arrow_pub.publish(arrow);
}


int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv,"my_pcl_tutorial");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("input",1,cloud_cb);
    pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output",1);
    arrow_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> ("out",1);
    ros::spin();
}
```

When I run `rostopic echo out` and `output` I can see both topics are published by the node but I cannot display them inside the ROS node.

Comment: Does it work if you comment out `arrow_pub.publish(arrow);` or it just worked before the changes?

Comment: if i dont use all the codes related to arrow, than it works. I was trying to add the sending arrow code from this tutorial:http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes,  inside the cloud_cb function, but i cant mix them.

Comment: Probably not what causes your problem, but if you really want point cloud and arrow to be displayed at the same time, you should not set the time stamp of the arrow to "now" but rather to the same stamp as the point cloud (probably something like `input.header.stamp`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the same `header.frame_id` for your pointcloud and marker messaages, then, In RVIZ, choose the correct topics and set the fixed frame as your frame_id value:

The code show be sth like this :

```
void publish(PointCloudPtr cloud)
{    
    cloud->header.frame_id = "/velodyne";
    pub_cloudObjects.publish (cloud);    
}


void add_marker( Eigen::Vector3f center, int number)
{
    visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
    // Set our shape type to be a cube, size & rgb
    uint32_t shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;
    marker.ns = "basic_shapes";
    marker.id = number;
    marker.type = shape;
    marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;

    marker.pose.position.x = (float)center(0);
    marker.pose.position.y = (float)center(1);
    marker.pose.position.z = (float)center(2);
    marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
    marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

    marker.scale.x = 0.5;
    marker.scale.y = 0.5;
    marker.scale.z = 0.5;

    marker.color.r = 0.0f;
    marker.color.g = 1.0f;
    marker.color.b = 0.0f;
    marker.color.a = 1.0;

    marker.lifetime = ros::Duration();
    marker.header.frame_id = "/velodyne";
    marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

    marker_pub.publish(marker);
}
```

and then in RVIZ :

```
Global Options:
    Fixed Frame: /velodyne
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: after getting the marker and point cloud together, how can i plot the marker at euclidean position (xw,yw,zw) which represents corresponding point in point cloud. for example if i calculated euclidean position of point (xp,yp) from depth image by using pcl than how should i show the exact point inside rviz by using marker, any idea?

Comment: first of all, if this answer solved your original question, please mark it as answered. Then, you can choose your marker position in RVIZ with the `marker.pose.position' values in (x,y,z).